# In Python, how can I prevent a class definition from being included multiple times?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am running into problems with a subclass with multiple superclasses calling its parents' **init** methods. I get an error about how unbound `__init__` needs instance of the parent, but got an instance of the child. Some other questions on StackOverflow pointed out that this is from the parent class being defined multiple times, which I confirmed with simple script typed into the interpreter.

Note: This is NOT the code I am asking the question about. It is an example to illustrate the problem of the Base class being re-defined and causing the Inherited class to no longer function properly.

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             print "Base!"
... 
>>> class Inherited(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...             Base.__init__(self)
...             print "Inherited"
... 
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             print "Base!"
... 
>>> Inherited()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Base instance as first argument (got Inherited instance instead)
>>>
```

My question is, how can I prevent the base class from being defined multiple times? The project I am working on has multiple files and imports all around, so it would be difficult to refactor everything to simply include the file once.

Comment: Simply importing the same module several times won't give you this problem. Something else must be going on. What is it?

Comment: You are creating this problem by creating two different classes called Base in the same, global namespace. Don't do this. Please show the code split into modules which demonstrates the same behaviour.

Comment: If `Base` is defined in a module, `import`ing that module multiple times only executes the definition the first time -- so that's not your problem. The sample code in your question is bogus because you're explicitly executing the definitions in the console, which is not the same thing.

Comment: This happens because `Base` is defined twice. No matter where and how this happens. Usind `super()` is the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Ber: Using `super()` might workaround the problem, but finding out _how_ it's happening at all when it shouldn't may prove to be more important.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior seems very fishy to me.  Importing the same module in different ways will still have your class (`Base`) refering to the same class object.  It seems unlikely that you could get into this situation via importing.

However, one workaround is to use `super`:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
            print "Base!"

class Inherited(Base):
    def __init__(self):
            super(Inherited,self).__init__()
            print "Inherited"

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
            print "Base!"

Inherited()
```

`super` ensures that you're actually calling the base-class's `__init__` rather than some other class which happened to take the place of the base-class in the current module's namespace.

Comment: OP should definitely be using `super` in any case, not just as a workaround.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- It's worth pointing out the various `super` articles that a simple google search will turn up:  ["super considered harmful"](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) and the corresponding ["super considered super"](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Rewriting the entire code base to use super() is unrealistic at this point.

Comment: @samoz It's literally a one line change per class.

Comment: @samoz -- I can understand if you wouldn't want to do that for one reason or another.  However, there isn't enough information in your original post to give you any other suggestions.  As I said in my answer, I can't see how you would get here if the problem was only from importing stuff.  Without being able to dig inside your code, I don't know if there's much more help we can offer.

Comment: @downvoter -- If you would leave a comment about what is wrong with this post, or how I can improve it, I would be happy to fix any errors or to try to make my answer more clear for the benefit of future SO users :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you identified above is because `Inherited` subclasses the original definition of `Base` (the first one you defined) as class definitions are processed as they are read.

However, at runtime, `__init__` of the *second* definition of `Base` is used. This class expects an instance of itself, but instead receives an instance of the first definition of `Base`.

When you type things in this way, the interpreter has no way of knowing that they are the same class. But when importing from a file, you won't have this problem as Python is smart enough to know that when a file is imported twice, the classes are the same.

Something else is going on with your code and it would be helpful to see more specific to your use case. The problem should only occur if you define a class with the same name in multiple modules and then import them into the same namespace.

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's already defined then? From what I can tell, the code base is doing a lot of importing and directory changing at runtime, which might cause some things to be re-imported incorrectly? Also, some of the code is inside of an __init__.py function, which changes it into a package, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can print out `Inherited.__bases__` and `Base` at the beginning of `__init__` in `Inherited`. This should show you where each of the two instances of `Base` is defined. If both show the same module path, then you may have `Base` defined twice in the same file.

Comment: @samos: This seems to be the correct analysis of the problem. The issue is scoping rule. You need to bind the `Base` class to the derived one. Using `super()` does this, but you could also include an explicit reference to the base class in the derived class' definition and use this instead of `Base`. It may also help if you avoid importing class names and instead qualify all classes with their module names.